# How to remove green suggestion box in CSS files in Sublime Text?

Tags: css, sublimetext3, emmet

When I type in a CSS file in Sublime Text 3, I get a green suggestion box and also suggestions underneath the line that I'm typing on. I would like to remove the green suggestions. I think it has to do with the Emmet plugin but I don't know what to do.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: There’s README for that: https://github.com/emmetio/sublime-text-plugin#expanding-abbreviation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was bugging me too!

Under Sublime Text menu > Preferences > Package Settings > Emmet > Settings

Add this to your user settings:

`"abbreviation_preview": false,`

See "Disable Abbreviation Capturing" here:
https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Emmet